# show dynamically selected columns in asp.net mvc grid at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik

I have an asp.net MVC application where I am using telerik grid to show the data/records.I am using the Entity Model.

My requirement is that sometime I want to show only some of the columns specified at the runtime/may the user select. How do I bind View with only those columns as selected by the user . Initially view is binded with Model class with all columns .

Is there any other way other than  telerik to show the  customized columns as selected by the user 
then it will be also OK .

Answer (score 1):

You could customize the columns that are shown using the `Columns` method. You need to have the information about which columns need to be shown in the view model so that you can at runtime select the columns to show:

```
<%= Html.Telerik()
        .Grid(Model.Customers)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            if (Model.IsShowFirstName)
            {
                columns.Bound(customer => customer.FirstName);
            }
            if (Model.IsShowLastName)
            {
                columns.Bound(customer => customer.LastName);
            }
        })
%>
```

Comment: Is the IsShowFirstName is the property  of the Model class

Comment: Yes, it is a property of the view model to which the view is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.Telerik() 
    .Grid(Model.Customers) 
    .Name("Grid") 
    .Columns(columns => 
    { 
        columns.Bound(customer => customer.FirstName).Visible(Model.IsShowFirstName); 
        columns.Bound(customer => customer.LastName).Visible(Model.IsShowLastName); 
    }) 
%>
```