# how to show dynamically selected columns in asp.net mvc grid at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an asp.net MVC application where I am using telerik grid to show the data/records.I am using the Entity Model.

My requirement is that sometime I want to show only some of the columns specified at the runtime/may the user select. How do I bind View with only those columns as selected by the user . Initially view is binded with Model class with all columns .

Is there any other way other than telerik to show the customized columns as selected by the user then it will be also OK .

Thanks In Advance

In below link, there is some solution, but can someone explain the solution how to populate model?

```
<%= Html.Telerik()        .Grid(Model.Customers)        .Name("Grid")        .Columns(columns =>        {            if (Model.IsShowFirstName)            {                columns.Bound(customer => customer.FirstName);            }            if (Model.IsShowLastName)            {                columns.Bound(customer => customer.LastName);            }        })%>
```

[show dynamically selected columns in asp.net mvc grid at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668086/show-dynamically-selected-columns-in-asp-net-mvc-grid-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Customers"] = db.cust_table.Where(w => w.cust_id == 1234);
    ViewData["IsShowFirstName"] = true;
    ViewData["IsShowLastName"] = false;

    return View();
}
```